# Why collection is not assigned to the backbone view in this code

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, jasmine

I am doing a spec testing for a backbone view written in coffeescript.

I have this view

```
class Test.Views.MainView extends Backbone.View
  el: $('ul')
  initialize: ->
    @collection.on 'add', @render
```

And here is my spec file

```
  beforeEach ->
    @collection = new Test.Collections.Services([{name:'test'}, {name:'build'}])
    @main_view = new Test.Views.MainView
      collection: @collection
```

When I run my spec, I got this error message

```
TypeError: this.collection is undefined
```

Why the collection isn't assigned to the view from the spec?

The compiled javascripts:

1. view.js

   ```
   Test.Views.MainView = (function(_super) {
       __extends(MainView, _super);

       function MainView() {
         this.render = __bind(this.render, this);
         _ref = MainView.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
         return _ref;
       }

       MainView.prototype.el = $('#main');

       MainView.prototype.initialize = function() {      
         this.collection.on('change', this.render); //this line generates the error     
       };
   ```
2. The spec

   ```
   beforeEach(function() {
     this.collection = new Test.Collections.Services([{name:'test'}, {name:'build'}]);
     return this.main_view = new Test.Views.MainView({
       collection: this.collection
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: Do you can show your compiled javascript?

Comment: Don't use the `@` notation in your tests. The test framework is functional, not object oriented, so using `@` is just confusing and creating unwanted global variables. I suspect this could be related to your test failing, although from inspection I don't see a specific error.

Comment: @Peter, thank you for the comment. How do I reference the variables in the test examples if not using @ ? And I marked the line which generates the error, are you able to find out what's the cause of the error? thanks.

Comment: In your `describe`, declare with with `collection = null` (this is a coffeescript thing) then assign them in `beforeEach` with `collection = new Collection()`.